# Display frequency (%) and count on a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame with three columns:

1. outcome: factor variable (with two rows)
2. n: integer variable displaying the number of time the factor variable appears in the data frame
3. freq: dbl variable displaying the frequency of the factor variable in the data set

   df <- data.frame(outcome = as.factor(c("Good", "Bad")),
                    n = c(700, 300), freq = c(70, 30))

I use the following code to create a bar chart based on the frequency of my factor variable:

```
library(ggplot2)  

ggplot(df, aes(x=outcome, y=freq, fill=outcome)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.4) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(freq,"%")), vjust=1.5, colour="white")
```

This code displays the frequency at the top each bar, something like this `70%` 
[image]

I want to display both the frequency and the count on top of my bar chart. Something like: `70% (4532)`
With, if possible, a line break between the percentage and the count.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: How about changing `label` to `paste0(freq, "%\n(", n, ")")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=outcome, y=freq, fill=outcome)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.4) +
 geom_text(aes(label=paste0(freq, "%\n(", n, ")"), vjust=1.5, colour="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Just a question, why do you have to write "%\n(", n, ")"and not simply "%\n", n

Comment: @remif so you can have brackets? - `70% (4532)`